# Querying data from Firebase collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working in the LAMP stack for years and am struggling to wrap my head around advanced querying with Firebase and NoSQL databases. I would like to return 5 random documents from a collection. Below is the VueJS code written thus far:

Here is the data object that I have created:

```
data () {
    return {
        courseIds: [],
    }
}
```

Here is my created lifecycle hook where I'm querying the Firebase NoSQL database:

```
created() {
    // fetch data from firestore
    database.collection('courses').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let course = doc.data()
                course.id  = doc.id

                this.courseIds.push(course.id)
            })
        })          
}
```

Because I'm looking to randomize the data returned, I have added the beforeMount lifecycle hook which calls a Fisher-Yates shuffle method. The plan was to shuffle the returned data and then return only the first 5 documents:

```
beforeMount() {
    this.courseIds = this.shuffle(this.courseIds)
}
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
    shuffle: function(array) {
        var m = array.length, t, i;

        while (m) {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

I'm a slow learner, so more than likely this is a numbskull approach to the problem. My present issue is that Firebase is returning the Ids as an object rather than an array so my shuffle method isn't working as anticipated. See the `console.log()` below:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0: "0HnqJ8zZg1Rs3D4qod4l"
1: "1gZmoUpCOSDeLsYMDi4v"
2: "JrJj3a84qKTD72ncvGXd"
3: "LWMbY98m3sKLrHNDSUkW"
4: "SUn1kxHzMo7fu5urpNB5"
5: "kQRWQIj0mFXIWVJcaouY"
length: 6
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(6), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Does anybody have a better approach to this functionality, or a good way to convert the courseIds into an array to be shuffled?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "Firebase is returning the Ids as an object rather than an array".

Comment: @DougStevenson Added the output of console.log(this.courseIds) to the question for more clarification.

Comment: I'm still confused. courseIds is an array because you made it that way.  You assigned it initially as an empty array, then pushed the IDs into it.  It's not really an object.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do a bit differently, as follows:

```
created() {
    // fetch data from firestore
    database.collection('courses').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            let courseIdsArray = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                courseIdsArray.push(doc.id);
            });    
            this.courseIds = courseIdsArray;
        });          
    }
```

Comment: This seems like it's the right direction, but where would I define `querySnapshot`?

Comment: Sorry, I copied/pasted some of my code too rapidly... I've adapted the answer.